# Track react-native restarts (reloads) and increment a counter

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to figure out how I can keep track of all the app reloads (live or hot) and increment a counter whenever the app restarts (reloads).

I haven't found the right place to do that.

Comment: One way of doing this is using the native platform lifecycle methods implementation

Comment: can you point me to what you mean @VickyAhuja? I'd be grateful.

Comment: checkout the answer and let me know if you find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I guess we can **use Native Platform's Lifecycle to achieve** this.

Suppose we are using *AsyncStorage to store our increment*.

First in android in our MainActivity, we can add code to read and update the counter in AsyncStorage in the **onCreate lifecycle method** of our Activity.

for iOS we can **add Event delegates in our AppDelegate** file to read and update the counter.